# Parse attributes and values from nested XML

Tags: groovy, xml-parsing, jira

Background: Trying to get all attributes and values from XML. I've tried using XmlParser as well as XmlSlurper.  I'm open to any other suggestions (this is a JIRA workflow in XML, trying to get the values to put into a report).

Running attributes() on it will not return anything at the top level. So running it into each() will make that available.  The first three return values work properly but the next 'level' doesn't, unless running each on each following array.  I am not really sure what to do on this. Each workflow will vary in length.  I thought about some sort of regex but that didn't seem like it would be workable with the different lengths and varieties of workflows.  This is a very basic workflow.  Others are much more complicated and the numbers of steps and attributes vary.
Running the children method returns the values but then it is a list, and not in the node class.  I put it here to show what it would return for values.  Any suggestions?

```
def xml =
    //'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n' +
    //'<!DOCTYPE workflow PUBLIC "-//OpenSymphony Group//DTD OSWorkflow 2.8//EN" "http://www.opensymphony.com/osworkflow/workflow_2_8.dtd">\n' +
    '<workflow>\n' +
            '  <meta name="jira.description"></meta>\n' +
            '  <meta name="jira.update.author.key">admin</meta>\n' +
            '  <meta name="jira.updated.date">1503954892468</meta>\n' +
            '  <initial-actions>\n' +
            '    <action id="1" name="Create">\n' +
            '      <meta name="jira.i18n.submit">common.forms.create</meta>\n' +
            '      <meta name="jira.i18n.title">common.forms.create</meta>\n' +
            '      <validators>\n' +
            '        <validator name="" type="class">\n' +
            '          <arg name="permission">Create Issue</arg>\n' +
            '          <arg name="class.name">com.atlassian.jira.workflow.validator.PermissionValidator</arg>\n' +
            '        </validator>\n' +
            '      </validators>\n' +
            '      <results>\n' +
            '        <unconditional-result old-status="null" status="open" step="1">\n' +
            '          <post-functions>\n' +
            '            <function type="class">\n' +
            '              <arg name="class.name">com.atlassian.jira.workflow.function.issue.IssueCreateFunction</arg>\n' +
            '            </function>\n' +
            '            <function type="class">\n' +
            '              <arg name="class.name">com.atlassian.jira.workflow.function.issue.IssueReindexFunction</arg>\n' +
            '            </function>\n' +
            '            <function type="class">\n' +
            '              <arg name="eventTypeId">1</arg>\n' +
            '              <arg name="class.name">com.atlassian.jira.workflow.function.event.FireIssueEventFunction</arg>\n' +
            '            </function>\n' +
            '          </post-functions>\n' +
            '        </unconditional-result>\n' +
            '      </results>\n' +
            '    </action>\n' +
            '  </initial-actions>\n' +
            '  <steps>\n' +
            '    <step id="1" name="To Do">\n' +
            '      <meta name="jira.status.id">10000</meta>\n' +
            '      <actions>\n' +
            '        <action id="11" name="Start Progress">\n' +
            '          <meta name="jira.i18n.submit">startprogress.title</meta>\n' +
            '          <meta name="jira.description"></meta>\n' +
            '          <meta name="jira.i18n.title">startprogress.title</meta>\n' +
            '          <results>\n' +
            '            <unconditional-result old-status="Not Done" status="Done" step="2">\n' +
            '              <post-functions>\n' +
            '                <function type="class">\n' +
            '                  <arg name="full.module.key">com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.workflowupdateissuestatus-function</arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="class.name">com.atlassian.jira.workflow.function.issue.UpdateIssueStatusFunction</arg>\n' +
            '                </function>\n' +
            '                <function type="class">\n' +
            '                  <arg name="full.module.key">com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.workflowassigntocurrentuser-function</arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="class.name">com.atlassian.jira.workflow.function.issue.AssignToCurrentUserFunction</arg>\n' +
            '                </function>\n' +
            '                <function type="class">\n' +
            '                  <arg name="full.module.key">com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.workflowcreatecomment-function</arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="class.name">com.atlassian.jira.workflow.function.misc.CreateCommentFunction</arg>\n' +
            '                </function>\n' +
            '                <function type="class">\n' +
            '                  <arg name="full.module.key">com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.workflowgeneratechangehistory-function</arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="class.name">com.atlassian.jira.workflow.function.issue.GenerateChangeHistoryFunction</arg>\n' +
            '                </function>\n' +
            '                <function type="class">\n' +
            '                  <arg name="full.module.key">com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.workflowreindexissue-function</arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="class.name">com.atlassian.jira.workflow.function.issue.IssueReindexFunction</arg>\n' +
            '                </function>\n' +
            '                <function type="class">\n' +
            '                  <arg name="eventTypeId">13</arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="full.module.key">com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.workflowfireevent-function</arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="class.name">com.atlassian.jira.workflow.function.event.FireIssueEventFunction</arg>\n' +
            '                </function>\n' +
            '              </post-functions>\n' +
            '            </unconditional-result>\n' +
            '          </results>\n' +
            '        </action>\n' +
            '        <action id="21" name="Done">\n' +
            '          <meta name="jira.i18n.submit">jira.issuetracking.simple.workflow.action.done.name</meta>\n' +
            '          <meta name="jira.description"></meta>\n' +
            '          <meta name="jira.i18n.title">jira.issuetracking.simple.workflow.action.done.name</meta>\n' +
            '          <restrict-to>\n' +
            '            <conditions>\n' +
            '              <condition type="class">\n' +
            '                <arg name="permission">RESOLVE_ISSUES</arg>\n' +
            '                <arg name="class.name">com.atlassian.jira.workflow.condition.PermissionCondition</arg>\n' +
            '              </condition>\n' +
            '            </conditions>\n' +
            '          </restrict-to>\n' +
            '          <results>\n' +
            '            <unconditional-result old-status="Not Done" status="Done" step="3">\n' +
            '              <post-functions>\n' +
            '                <function type="class">\n' +
            '                  <arg name="field.name">resolution</arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="field.value">10000</arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="class.name">com.atlassian.jira.workflow.function.issue.UpdateIssueFieldFunction</arg>\n' +
            '                </function>\n' +
            '                <function type="class">\n' +
            '                  <arg name="full.module.key">com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.workflowupdateissuestatus-function</arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="class.name">com.atlassian.jira.workflow.function.issue.UpdateIssueStatusFunction</arg>\n' +
            '                </function>\n' +
            '                <function type="class">\n' +
            '                  <arg name="full.module.key">com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.workflowcreatecomment-function</arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="class.name">com.atlassian.jira.workflow.function.misc.CreateCommentFunction</arg>\n' +
            '                </function>\n' +
            '                <function type="class">\n' +
            '                  <arg name="full.module.key">com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.workflowgeneratechangehistory-function</arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="class.name">com.atlassian.jira.workflow.function.issue.GenerateChangeHistoryFunction</arg>\n' +
            '                </function>\n' +
            '                <function type="class">\n' +
            '                  <arg name="full.module.key">com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.workflowreindexissue-function</arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="class.name">com.atlassian.jira.workflow.function.issue.IssueReindexFunction</arg>\n' +
            '                </function>\n' +
            '                <function type="class">\n' +
            '                  <arg name="eventTypeId">13</arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="full.module.key">com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.workflowfireevent-function</arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="class.name">com.atlassian.jira.workflow.function.event.FireIssueEventFunction</arg>\n' +
            '                </function>\n' +
            '              </post-functions>\n' +
            '            </unconditional-result>\n' +
            '          </results>\n' +
            '        </action>\n' +
            '      </actions>\n' +
            '    </step>\n' +
            '    <step id="2" name="In Progress">\n' +
            '      <meta name="jira.status.id">3</meta>\n' +
            '      <actions>\n' +
            '        <action id="31" name="Stop Progress">\n' +
            '          <meta name="jira.i18n.submit">stopprogress.title</meta>\n' +
            '          <meta name="jira.description"></meta>\n' +
            '          <meta name="jira.i18n.title">stopprogress.title</meta>\n' +
            '          <results>\n' +
            '            <unconditional-result old-status="Not Done" status="Done" step="1">\n' +
            '              <post-functions>\n' +
            '                <function type="class">\n' +
            '                  <arg name="full.module.key">com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.workflowupdateissuestatus-function</arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="class.name">com.atlassian.jira.workflow.function.issue.UpdateIssueStatusFunction</arg>\n' +
            '                </function>\n' +
            '                <function type="class">\n' +
            '                  <arg name="full.module.key">com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.workflowcreatecomment-function</arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="class.name">com.atlassian.jira.workflow.function.misc.CreateCommentFunction</arg>\n' +
            '                </function>\n' +
            '                <function type="class">\n' +
            '                  <arg name="full.module.key">com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.workflowgeneratechangehistory-function</arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="class.name">com.atlassian.jira.workflow.function.issue.GenerateChangeHistoryFunction</arg>\n' +
            '                </function>\n' +
            '                <function type="class">\n' +
            '                  <arg name="full.module.key">com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.workflowreindexissue-function</arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="class.name">com.atlassian.jira.workflow.function.issue.IssueReindexFunction</arg>\n' +
            '                </function>\n' +
            '                <function type="class">\n' +
            '                  <arg name="eventTypeId">13</arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="full.module.key">com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.workflowfireevent-function</arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="class.name">com.atlassian.jira.workflow.function.event.FireIssueEventFunction</arg>\n' +
            '                </function>\n' +
            '              </post-functions>\n' +
            '            </unconditional-result>\n' +
            '          </results>\n' +
            '        </action>\n' +
            '        <action id="41" name="Done">\n' +
            '          <meta name="jira.i18n.submit">jira.issuetracking.simple.workflow.action.done.name</meta>\n' +
            '          <meta name="jira.description"></meta>\n' +
            '          <meta name="jira.i18n.title">jira.issuetracking.simple.workflow.action.done.name</meta>\n' +
            '          <restrict-to>\n' +
            '            <conditions>\n' +
            '              <condition type="class">\n' +
            '                <arg name="permission">RESOLVE_ISSUES</arg>\n' +
            '                <arg name="class.name">com.atlassian.jira.workflow.condition.PermissionCondition</arg>\n' +
            '              </condition>\n' +
            '            </conditions>\n' +
            '          </restrict-to>\n' +
            '          <results>\n' +
            '            <unconditional-result old-status="Not Done" status="Done" step="3">\n' +
            '              <post-functions>\n' +
            '                <function type="class">\n' +
            '                  <arg name="field.name">resolution</arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="field.value">10000</arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="class.name">com.atlassian.jira.workflow.function.issue.UpdateIssueFieldFunction</arg>\n' +
            '                </function>\n' +
            '                <function type="class">\n' +
            '                  <arg name="full.module.key">com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.workflowupdateissuestatus-function</arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="class.name">com.atlassian.jira.workflow.function.issue.UpdateIssueStatusFunction</arg>\n' +
            '                </function>\n' +
            '                <function type="class">\n' +
            '                  <arg name="full.module.key">com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.workflowcreatecomment-function</arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="class.name">com.atlassian.jira.workflow.function.misc.CreateCommentFunction</arg>\n' +
            '                </function>\n' +
            '                <function type="class">\n' +
            '                  <arg name="full.module.key">com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.workflowgeneratechangehistory-function</arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="class.name">com.atlassian.jira.workflow.function.issue.GenerateChangeHistoryFunction</arg>\n' +
            '                </function>\n' +
            '                <function type="class">\n' +
            '                  <arg name="full.module.key">com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.workflowreindexissue-function</arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="class.name">com.atlassian.jira.workflow.function.issue.IssueReindexFunction</arg>\n' +
            '                </function>\n' +
            '                <function type="class">\n' +
            '                  <arg name="eventTypeId">13</arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="full.module.key">com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.workflowfireevent-function</arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="class.name">com.atlassian.jira.workflow.function.event.FireIssueEventFunction</arg>\n' +
            '                </function>\n' +
            '              </post-functions>\n' +
            '            </unconditional-result>\n' +
            '          </results>\n' +
            '        </action>\n' +
            '      </actions>\n' +
            '    </step>\n' +
            '    <step id="3" name="Done">\n' +
            '      <meta name="jira.status.id">10001</meta>\n' +
            '      <actions>\n' +
            '        <action id="51" name="Reopen">\n' +
            '          <meta name="jira.i18n.submit">jira.issuetracking.simple.workflow.action.reopen.name</meta>\n' +
            '          <meta name="jira.description"></meta>\n' +
            '          <meta name="jira.i18n.title">jira.issuetracking.simple.workflow.action.reopen.name</meta>\n' +
            '          <restrict-to>\n' +
            '            <conditions>\n' +
            '              <condition type="class">\n' +
            '                <arg name="permission">RESOLVE_ISSUES</arg>\n' +
            '                <arg name="class.name">com.atlassian.jira.workflow.condition.PermissionCondition</arg>\n' +
            '              </condition>\n' +
            '            </conditions>\n' +
            '          </restrict-to>\n' +
            '          <results>\n' +
            '            <unconditional-result old-status="Not Done" status="Done" step="1">\n' +
            '              <post-functions>\n' +
            '                <function type="class">\n' +
            '                  <arg name="field.name">resolution</arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="field.value"></arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="class.name">com.atlassian.jira.workflow.function.issue.UpdateIssueFieldFunction</arg>\n' +
            '                </function>\n' +
            '                <function type="class">\n' +
            '                  <arg name="full.module.key">com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.workflowupdateissuestatus-function</arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="class.name">com.atlassian.jira.workflow.function.issue.UpdateIssueStatusFunction</arg>\n' +
            '                </function>\n' +
            '                <function type="class">\n' +
            '                  <arg name="full.module.key">com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.workflowcreatecomment-function</arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="class.name">com.atlassian.jira.workflow.function.misc.CreateCommentFunction</arg>\n' +
            '                </function>\n' +
            '                <function type="class">\n' +
            '                  <arg name="full.module.key">com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.workflowgeneratechangehistory-function</arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="class.name">com.atlassian.jira.workflow.function.issue.GenerateChangeHistoryFunction</arg>\n' +
            '                </function>\n' +
            '                <function type="class">\n' +
            '                  <arg name="full.module.key">com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.workflowreindexissue-function</arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="class.name">com.atlassian.jira.workflow.function.issue.IssueReindexFunction</arg>\n' +
            '                </function>\n' +
            '                <function type="class">\n' +
            '                  <arg name="eventTypeId">13</arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="full.module.key">com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.workflowfireevent-function</arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="class.name">com.atlassian.jira.workflow.function.event.FireIssueEventFunction</arg>\n' +
            '                </function>\n' +
            '              </post-functions>\n' +
            '            </unconditional-result>\n' +
            '          </results>\n' +
            '        </action>\n' +
            '        <action id="61" name="Reopen and start progress">\n' +
            '          <meta name="jira.i18n.submit">jira.issuetracking.simple.workflow.action.reopenandstartprogress.name</meta>\n' +
            '          <meta name="jira.description"></meta>\n' +
            '          <meta name="jira.i18n.title">jira.issuetracking.simple.workflow.action.reopenandstartprogress.name</meta>\n' +
            '          <results>\n' +
            '            <unconditional-result old-status="Not Done" status="Done" step="2">\n' +
            '              <post-functions>\n' +
            '                <function type="class">\n' +
            '                  <arg name="field.name">resolution</arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="field.value"></arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="class.name">com.atlassian.jira.workflow.function.issue.UpdateIssueFieldFunction</arg>\n' +
            '                </function>\n' +
            '                <function type="class">\n' +
            '                  <arg name="full.module.key">com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.workflowupdateissuestatus-function</arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="class.name">com.atlassian.jira.workflow.function.issue.UpdateIssueStatusFunction</arg>\n' +
            '                </function>\n' +
            '                <function type="class">\n' +
            '                  <arg name="full.module.key">com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.workflowassigntocurrentuser-function</arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="class.name">com.atlassian.jira.workflow.function.issue.AssignToCurrentUserFunction</arg>\n' +
            '                </function>\n' +
            '                <function type="class">\n' +
            '                  <arg name="full.module.key">com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.workflowcreatecomment-function</arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="class.name">com.atlassian.jira.workflow.function.misc.CreateCommentFunction</arg>\n' +
            '                </function>\n' +
            '                <function type="class">\n' +
            '                  <arg name="full.module.key">com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.workflowgeneratechangehistory-function</arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="class.name">com.atlassian.jira.workflow.function.issue.GenerateChangeHistoryFunction</arg>\n' +
            '                </function>\n' +
            '                <function type="class">\n' +
            '                  <arg name="full.module.key">com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.workflowreindexissue-function</arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="class.name">com.atlassian.jira.workflow.function.issue.IssueReindexFunction</arg>\n' +
            '                </function>\n' +
            '                <function type="class">\n' +
            '                  <arg name="eventTypeId">13</arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="full.module.key">com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.workflowfireevent-function</arg>\n' +
            '                  <arg name="class.name">com.atlassian.jira.workflow.function.event.FireIssueEventFunction</arg>\n' +
            '                </function>\n' +
            '              </post-functions>\n' +
            '            </unconditional-result>\n' +
            '          </results>\n' +
            '        </action>\n' +
            '      </actions>\n' +
            '    </step>\n' +
            '  </steps>\n' +
            '</workflow>\n' +
            ''

def doc = new XmlParser().parseText(xml)
def attr = doc.attributes() //no results

doc.each {

    if (it.attributes()) {
        println( it.name() )
        println( it.attributes() )
        println( it.value() )
        println ""
    }   else  {
       println ( it.children() )

    }

    }
```

Output:

```
meta
[name:jira.description]
[]

meta
[name:jira.update.author.key]
[admin]

meta
[name:jira.updated.date]
[1503954892468]

[action[attributes={id=1, name=Create}; value=[meta[attributes={name=jira.i18n.submit}; value=[common.forms.create]], meta[attributes={name=jira.i18n.title}; value=[common.forms.create]], validators[attributes={}; value=[validator[attributes={name=, type=class}; value=[arg[attributes={name=permission}; value=[Create Issue]], arg[attributes={name=class.name}; value=[com.atlassian.jira.workflow.validator.PermissionValidator]]]]]], results[attributes={}; value=[unconditional-result[attributes={old-status=null, status=open, step=1}; value=[post-functions[attributes={}; value=[function[attributes={type=class}; value=[arg[attributes={name=class.name}; value=[com.atlassian.jira.workflow.function.issue.IssueCreateFunction]]]], function[attributes={type=class}; value=[arg[attributes={name=class.name}; value=[com.atlassian.jira.workflow.function.issue.IssueReindexFunction]]]], function[attributes={type=class}; value=[arg[attributes={name=eventTypeId}; value=[1]], arg[attributes={name=class.name}; value=[com.atlassian.jira.workflow.function.event.FireIssueEventFunction]]]]]]]]]]]]]
...
```

Desired Output:
Getting all attributes and values, preferably in some format like this:

```
attribute name :   value

jira.updated.date : 1503954892468

jira.update.author.key : admin
```

Comment: what is the issue exactly. Is the output shown is correct or not? If not, what is desired output.

Comment: I've added a section at the bottom; just getting the attribute name and the related value. The problem isn't that the output values are incorrect, just that I'm not yet able to get them in a format that is easy to read (rather than following along the array) and shows the attributes and corresponding values.

Comment: Do you want the attributes of all `<meta>` element only?

Comment: For all the elements if possible. (I could try looking for each element by name, but as the workflows change it might be difficult to make sure to get all of them).  I appreciate your help!

Comment: Did you try the given solution atleast? was it fine?

Comment: Yes, that works well. Would it be possible to limit it to search a particular node or section of the xml if it came down to that, rather than the entire document (to see the results in the context of that node?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below script would -

- find all the `meta` elements
- create a map with `name` attribute and its text
- finally prints the map.

Not including `xml` string to avoid big space, anyway you have it.

```
def metas = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml).'**'.findAll {it.name() == 'meta'}
def metaAttributeMap = metas.collectEntries{ [(it.@name):it.text()]}
metaAttributeMap.each {k,v -> println "$k : $v"}
```

You can quickly try the same online <kbd>[demo](https://ideone.com/rzFBiM)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for your help.  This only gets the <meta> elements.  Is there another way to use a wildcard character to return all the elements with attributes and values?  There are instances where it isn't clear what the attributes will be in advance. 

Example:
<step id="1" name="To Do">